# Form submit using Java

Tags: java, forms, jsf, submit, viewstate

I have a JSF 1.2 login page (login.xhtml) that has 2 sub-forms - menuForm, loginForm.

Using a browser, I am able to navigate from the login page to a productList.xhtml page by clicking on the Login button within the loginForm.

....

For allowing the Google Crawler to crawl through my pages that require login, I am trying to test a form submit with a Java program on the loginForm to see if I can retrieve the productList.xhtml page.

The hidden fields (View Source from browser) in the login.xhtml page includes the following: 
username
password
autoScroll
loginForm
loginButton
javax.faces.ViewState

I have submitted all the values from above (except the javax.faces.ViewState) in my Java program, but I keep getting only the login.xhtml page back in my response. Why is this?

I cannot submit the javax.faces.ViewState because there is no state on the server-side for the form when a submit happens from the Java program. How do I submit a form that does not yet have a view state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *For allowing the Google Crawler to crawl through my pages that require login*

A login requires a session (basically: a cookie). But web crawlers does not maintain the session (basically: they do not maintain cookies). So it ends up here. You have to remove the login form and replace all navigation commandlinks by normal links in order to let any webcrawler index your pages.

It's by the way beyond me why you would like to make restricted pages crawlable (thus: publicitly available). Why is the login there in first instance?

---

> *I have submitted all the values from above (except the javax.faces.ViewState) in my Java program, but I keep getting only the login.xhtml page back in my response. Why is this?*

Because you omitted the view state field. JSF won't process the form submit then. For a part, this is a safeguard against CSRF attacks and for other part, this is because JSF is a stateful component based MVC framework.

---

> *I cannot submit the javax.faces.ViewState because there is no state on the server-side for the form when a submit happens from the Java program. How do I submit a form that does not yet have a view state?*

You need to either maintain the session (basically: send all cookies from the server back in subsequent requests), or to set the state saving method in `web.xml` to `client` **and** you also need to pass the view state hidden field along with the form submit request.

Comment: The primary reason for allowing Google to crawl through my restricted pages is because this seems to be the new way with Adsense since 31-Aug-2011. My site has about 5600 public pages so far with maybe about 200 restricted pages for each user, but Google Adsense keeps rejecting my application with the reason "Login Only".

Comment: Ah well. Either just don't put Google ads on those pages then or make a public version of those pages with limited features/rights/buttons/etc, like as you see on discussion forums and Q&A sites.